# Export user's group memberships to a text file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm new to powershell and after fiddling for about 3 hours now... I'm asking the experts...

I need to setup a scrip that will prompt for a user's ad id and then export just the canonical names of the groups he/she is in to a text file.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This is not a code writing service. Try writing the script yourself and post here when you have a concrete problem. Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Cool, I'll figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to at least get you started you want to be looking at the cmdlet

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership
```

If you do "Help Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership" you can see the parameters. It accepts -identity so you can just give it the samacount of an ad user.

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity testuser
```

This will return more information that what you really want, so finally you can filter it down to what you are really looking for by selecting specific properties.

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity testuser | select distinguishedname
```

To prompt someone to enter information you can do "Read-Host". Beyond that research variables and you should be able to put this all together into something that prompts a user for id then searches.

Comment: Noah, you win the internet today...

I got as far at the principalgroupmembership thing but was totally stumped on filtering the output!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could assist you a bit. A couple more tips outside of utilizing Help would be "Get-Command" you can use this to explore cmdlets you might need, like if you were looking for AD cmdlets you can do `Get-Command *AD*`. And the other tip is research "Get-Member". You can pipe things to this to explore the object type and available properties.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago, I've created such a script complete with GUI for my colleagues to use.
You just input the user and it will export into a csv file the group name, group category (security/distribution) and the group scope (global/universal)
I think it's better to export the groups in a csv file rather then a txt file.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

Function ExportMailboxMembers{
$Input = $InputBox.Text
$ReportPath = “C:\temp\$($Input)_UserGroups.csv“

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $Input | select name, groupcategory, groupscope | 
export-CSV “C:\temp\$($Input)_UserGroups.csv“ -NoTypeInformation

Add-OutputBoxLine -Message "The csv file has been successfully exported to 
C:\temp\$($Input)_UserGroups.csv
                       You may now click the EXIT button."
}

Function Add-OutputBoxLine {
    Param ($Message)
    $OutputBox.AppendText("`r`n$Message")
    $OutputBox.Refresh()
    $OutputBox.ScrollToCaret()
}

#Creating the Form
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Export User Groups to CSV ~ made by Victor G." 
$Form.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (800,600)

#Adding Label 1
$Label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

$Label1.Text = "Imput the user for which you wish to export the groups to a CSV 
file (ex. jsnow)"
$Label1.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$Label1.AutoSize = $true
$Form.Controls.Add($Label1)

#Adding Label 2
$Label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

$Label2.Text = "System response here:"
$Label2.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,120)
$Label2.AutoSize = $true
$Form.Controls.Add($Label2)

#Adding imput box
$InputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (20,50)
$InputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (300,20)
$Form.Controls.Add($InputBox)

#Adding an outbox
$OutputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$OutputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (10,150)
$OutputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,300)
$OutputBox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial",12, 
[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$OutputBox.Multiline = $true
$OutputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$OutputBox.ReadOnly = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($OutputBox)

#Adding the button
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (600,50)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (150,100)
$Button.Text = "Export groups"
$Button.Add_click({ExportMailboxMembers})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)

$ButtonCloseSkript = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$ButtonCloseSkript.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(650,500) 
$ButtonCloseSkript.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(92,30) 
$ButtonCloseSkript.Text = "EXIT" 
$ButtonCloseSkript.Add_Click({$Form.Close()})#On click do function
$ButtonCloseSkript.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand 
$Form.Controls.Add($ButtonCloseSkript)

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a script I use for getting a user's distribution groups. It will also give you the option to remove the user from all groups at the end, which I use when I'm forwarding a terminated employee's email. This could be easily modified to export to a text file instead of printing to screen.

```
write-host ""
$User = Get-Mailbox (Read-Host -Prompt "User Name") | Select-Object Name,DistinguishedName


#script

Write-Host ""
$User.Name + " is a member of the following groups:"
Write-Host ""


$groups = (Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize unlimited | Select-Object identity,displayname)
$i = $groups.Count
$j = 0

    $usersgroups = @(
        foreach ($group in $groups) {
            Write-Progress -Activity $group.DisplayName -Status "$i Groups Remaining.."  -PercentComplete (($j / $groups.count)*100)
            $i--
            $j++

            if ((Get-DistributionGroupMember $group.identity | Select-Object -ExpandProperty distinguishedname) -contains $user.DistinguishedName) {
                $group.displayname
                Write-Host $group.DisplayName
            }
        }
    )



#option to remove user from groups

Write-Host ""
if ((Read-Host "Do you want to remove user from these groups? y/n").ToLower() -like 'y*') { 
    Write-Host ""

    foreach ($group in $usersgroups){
        Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $User.Name -confirm: $false -Verbose
    }
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Done!"
} ELSE {
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Aborting Script!"
}
```

Comment: While this is a good script this does not answer the ops question. This is for use with Exchange and i think the op is looking for all AD groups. Also please dont support poor questions.